# Ruby on Rails: How can I use a redirect_to in a link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect to a certain page after an action (handled by a gem) is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects are handled in the controller.

Example:

```
def update
  @model.save
  redirect_to model_path(@model)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in 3 ways

1) using render :action

def update
  @model.save
  render :action => "page_name"
end
here it will take you on "page_name" page

2) render :template => "page_name"
here it will take you on "page_name" page

3) using redirect_to